# Object variable as key and value assignment

Tags: javascript

What is this syntax called in JS:

```js
let name = "asdf";
let obj = { name }; // <-- this
```

Comment: People usually refer to it as "short-hand property initialisation" (or variations of this) but there is no real technically distinct name for it, though, as it's part of the object initialiser/literal grammar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions